# Data analytics architecture

Tags: dashboard, data-analysis

I have DB which holds some data. That data is transformed in required format before storing in that DB. Also that DB is queried by production applications.

Note that there's no raw data DB, all data is processed for further usage in our applications before we're inserting it in that noSQL.
Now i need to implement some reports based on this data.

For example by selecting dates range in UI generate simple chart to show collected data trend by date:

[image: Chart]

Of course it's simple example to understand what i need and trying to achieve, real reports would be more complicated.

In principle i'm looking for most common and smartest way to join this two sub-systems ( data DB and analytics ) to achieve following result: *query the same data by reports which is queried by applications.*

There i see some challenges and difficulties because heavy reports would impact DB throughput and since same DB is also used by applications slows them down too.
If there is already some principles building systems like this i would be grateful if you mention it in comments / answers.

Since i could not find any guidelines i'll describe mine thoughts how to implement analytics:

- Send these counts like "events" thought some messaging platform ( [RabitQM](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) ) to another application which will store this data to separate DB and uses it later in reports. I see following pros and cons in this approach:

  - Pros: No performance impact in dashboard platform.
  - Cons: Data duplication

Comment: Please be more precise about "mined data". Data mining is a massive field, and some people a use this buzzword for simple aggregates, or web scraping. Don't play buzzword bingo here, this is not a business sales pitch.

Answer (score -1):

So you have a DB currently used by a transactional application,
and you are going to build an analytic application on top of the data from that DB, but concern about the performance impact added to the transactional application.

One common practice is similar to what you are thinking, replicate the data
into another database for analytic purpose.

The application subsystem is an OLTP system,
the analytic subsystem is an OLAP system. The process of transforming data from OLTP DB to OLAP DB is called ETL. Your idea of replicating the data through messaging queue
into another DB is one possible custom ETL approach.

Usually in OLAP system you use star schema or OLAP Cube to store pre-aggregated data, so that reporting application can query the data from DB with better performance. Most of the reporting tools (BI tools), like Tableau, Cognos, SSRS can read data from star schema. Even if you are not going to use any of these tools, just want to build the report UI with custom code, star schema would be helpful as well.

Now reporting and application are using different DB, there will be a time lag between these two. If using a messaging queue to transform data into analytic DB at real time, then the time lag will be minimal. However there's a cost when adding new data to OLAP DB, if you pre-aggregate the data in order to get better query performance. That's why a lot of reporting system usually doesn't report on realtime data, if the time lag is acceptable for business.